# How to match a word in a string using a regex and performing a specific task on each match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a written a function that matches a `.filter()` clause in my query, but this functions matches the word just one time and then does not match for further occurrence.

```
function insertStringInQuery(sampleQuery, stringToInsert)
        {
            var matchFilter = sampleQuery.match(/\.filter\((.*?)\)/);
            console.log('matchFilter',matchFilter)
            var stringToInsert = stringToInsert+"&";
            var sliceIndex = matchFilter.index+8;
            var finalQueryVal = sampleQuery.slice(0, sliceIndex) + 
                    stringToInsert +
                    sampleQuery.slice(sliceIndex, sampleQuery.len);
            return finalQueryVal
        }
```

how can I make it to match every `.filter()` in 'sampleQuery' and insert the string ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `g` flag to get more than one result :

```
var matchFilter = sampleQuery.match(/\.filter\((.*?)\)/g);
```

This gives you a string array on which you can easily iterate.

For example

```
"test.filter(f) a.filter(e)".match(/\.filter\((.*?)\)/g)
```

gives you

```
[".filter(f)", ".filter(e)"]
```

Now, suppose that you want to get also the submatch. The easiest solution is to use exec :

```
var str = "test.filter(f) a.filter(e)";
var regex = /\.filter\((.*?)\)/g, m;
while (m=regex.exec(str)){
  console.log(m[0], m[1]) 
}
```

This logs

```
.filter(f) f
.filter(e) e
```

If what you want, as it seems, is only to add `&` at the start of the submatches, you could use replace :

```
"test.filter(f) a.filter(e)".replace(/(\.filter\()(.*?)\)/g, "$1&$2)")
```

gives you

```
test.filter(&f) a.filter(&e)
```

Comment: Side info: `g` for global.

Comment: When I add 'g' to my regex the string is concatenated at the start of the query. Anyother way please?

Comment: @MHS I'm trying to get what you try to achieve. See edit (at the end). Is that what you want ?